# Return true if and only if all values in array are true?

Tags: php, forms, validation

So I have an array that contains all of the function calls to check the input of a form.  I then have a foreach loop through the array to see if the returns from the validate functions are true or false.  Depending on that outcome the function that the foreach is in returns either true or false.  The problem I'm trying to figure out is how to return true just once if all of the validate functions come back true.

Here is my code:

```
public function valInputs()
{
    $valArray = array(
        valName($firstName),
        valName($lastName),
        valPhone($phone),
        valEmail($email)
    ); // these functions return true/false depending on validation

    foreach($valArray as $value)
    {
        if(!$value)
        {
            return false;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
           return true; // the problem is, true gets returned X number of times
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how to keep true from returning multiple times?  Thank you for any help.

Comment: No. That function will return *exactly once*.

Comment: However, the answer to "correcting the behavior" (everything else aside) is to put the `return true` *outside* the `for` (after it) and remove the `break` (as it will never be executed after the return).

Comment: Freethink a little harder. Hint: you don't *need* an `else`...

Comment: where are u calling this function ?

Comment: I have made the title more generic. I hope that it helps this post along. (There are multiple ways to skin a cat. For instance, if any element is *false* then it is not the case that all elements are *true*.)

Comment: You sure you need a foreach loop and an array? It doesn't look like so judging from the example you posted.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The return call stops the foreach loop AND the function. You can in fact just return true beneath the loop:

```
foreach($valArray as $value)
{
    if(!$value)
    {
        return false;
        // break is not needed, and should NOT be used in this case,
        // as it stops the foreach loop.
        // It will never be reached anyways, seeing how you return false just above.
    }
}
return true;
```

If it reaches the end of the loop, it means it hasn't returned false. Hence it should return true.

Comment: but this doesnt matter. He is calling the function multiple times. Where ever you place the return statement it will kick u out of the function once return is hit.

Comment: Deepak, the issue is the first true value he returns true, and the loop stops. so it only checks if there is 1 true-value.

Comment: @Deepak, he has it returning false if he finds a bad value (good).
But he has it returning true when he finds a good value (bad). he wants to make sure every value is good before he returns true.

Answer (score 4):

An interesting way to do it would be

```
public function valInputs()
{
    $valArray = array(
        valName($firstName),
        valName($lastName),
        valPhone($phone),
        valEmail($email)
    ); // these functions return true/false depending on validation

return array_product( $valArray ) === 1; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why not just:

```
public function valInputs() {
    return (valName($firstName) && valName($lastName) && valPhone($phone) && valEmail($email));
}
```

This will return true if all of them are true, false if at least one of them is false. Frankly I'm not sure why would you need a foreach loop there.

Comment: That's the way I was checking them and I wanted a more elegant solution.  Thank you for the answer though.

Comment: @Freethinker IMHO a foreach loop is not elegant in this case, but up to you.

Comment: That's what `array_product` is for.

Comment: @aziz.punjani that works too, but it's not quite as readable. At the end of the day code that is instantaneously obvious what it does wins over workarounds, but well, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, return ends the function. You can't return more than once.

Look at pst's comment, check to see if you are calling that function multiple times.